# Integrate $\int_x^\infty (1-3y^{-4})\exp(-y^2/2)dy$

Tags: integration

On page 11 from Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*, he bounds the Gaussian distribution function and states that
\begin{align}
\int_x^\infty (1-3y^{-4})\exp(-y^2/2)dy=(x^{-1}-x^{-3})\exp(-x^2/2)
\end{align}

How do we get this?

Comment: Just verify that $$-\frac{d}{dx} \left[ (x^{-1}-x^{-3})\exp(-x^2/2) \right]= (1-3x^{-4})\exp(-x^2/2)$$ and the rest follows from NL formula

Comment: What is the NL formula?

Comment: The Netwon-Leibniz formula: $$\int_a^b F'(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)$$

Comment: Thanks.  If I wanted to solve it without assuming I know the RHS, how would you go about doing it?  Integration by parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do repeated integration by parts:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int {\left( {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}} - \frac{3}{{{y^4}}}{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}} \right)dy}  &= \int {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}dy}  + \int {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}d(\frac{1}{{{y^3}}})} \\
&= \frac{1}{{{y^3}}}{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}} + \int {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}dy}  + \int {\frac{1}{{{y^2}}}{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}dy} \\
& = \frac{1}{{{y^3}}}{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}} + \int {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}dy}  - \int {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}d(\frac{1}{y})} \\
& = \frac{1}{{{y^3}}}{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}} - {e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}\frac{1}{y} + \int {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}dy}  - \int {{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}dy} \\
& = \frac{1}{{{y^3}}}{e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}} - {e^{ - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}}}\frac{1}{y} + C \end{aligned} $$